# Add one point to each point in an numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Sat I have the following numpy array:

```
arr = numpy.array([[0,0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]])
```

How do I add a single sub-array  on each of the six sub-arrays? (Say if want to add `[2,1]` to each of them then the output should be `[[2,1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1]]`)

I know if it's a 1D array you can just write something like `arr + 1` and it will add 1 to each elements in arr but what about in this case? I have yet to be able to find relative information in the documentations

Comment: Just add it: `arr + [2, 1`]. Numpy follows broadcasting rules which are explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.array([np.append(item, [2,1]) for item in arr])
```

This should give you the result